# How to open a component.html in a new window in Electron with Angular?

Tags: angular, electron

I'm setting up a simple project made in Electron with Angular 7 (using this project https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron).

**How can I open a component.html in a new window?**

I have done this:

```
    createBrowserWindow() {
    const remote = this.electronService.remote;
    const BrowserWindow = this.electronService.remote.BrowserWindow;
    var win = new BrowserWindow({
     height: 600,
     width: 800
     });



    win.loadURL(this.electronService.url.format({
      pathname: this.electronService.path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
      hash: '/inicio'
    }) 
    ); 

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    win.on('closed', () => {
      win = null
    });
  }
```

**But when I call the method, an error arise:**

> zone.js:703 Unhandled Promise rejection: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (-6) loading 'file:///C:/Users/xx/Documents/projectName/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/renderer/index.html#/inicio' ;

**Then a new window is opened and this message appears:**

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/xx/Documents/projecName/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/renderer/index.html#/inicio

Comment: Can upload the code into a new branch in your propject and we download and try the error? It's simple (I think) because I have in a project that have this functionality

Comment: oh sorry, I can't upload the project since it is restricted by the university :/

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import * as path from "path";
import * as url from "url";
let win: BrowserWindow;
app.on("ready", createWindow);
app.on("activate", () => {
if (win === null) {
 createWindow();
}
});
function createWindow() {
 win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
 win.loadURL(
url.format({
  pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/../../dist/angular-electron/index.html`),
  protocol: "file:",
  slashes: true
})
);
win.webContents.openDevTools();
win.on("closed", () => {
win = null;
});
}
```

I hope this will  solve ur problem....Happy Coding. Thanks